# Custom loading screen during VR to VR transition ? (Oculus GO | Oculus Browser | A-Frame | Three.js )

Tags: chromium, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr, oculusgo

Is it possible for us to control the loading screen of browser during VR to VR transition ? I am currently using a oculus go (oculus browser) for development. The default loading screen is a void space with a spinner and  it would be nice to have custom content during that transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible. Once you leave a page after navigation the browser is in control of what it’s rendered on screen until the new page loads.